# how to avoid subqueries for views in linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm using linq to retrieve data in MVC 4 from tables and views classes.
If I use linq for extracting data from view, like this:

```
db.vwContractMVC.Where(x => x.NID == id && x.Date >= pin && x.Date <= pen).ToList();
```

then linq constructs the sql query with subquery like this:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[NID] AS [NID], 
[Extent1].[Date] AS [Date], 
[Extent1].[Column1] AS [Column1], 
[Extent1].[Column2] AS [Column2], 
[Extent1].[Column3] AS [Column3]
FROM (SELECT 
      [vwContractMVC].[NID] AS [NID], 
      [vwContractMVC].[Date] AS [Date], 
      [vwContractMVC].[Column1] AS [Column1], 
      [vwContractMVC].[Column2] AS [Column2], 
      [vwContractMVC].[Column3] AS [Column3]
      FROM [dbo].[vwContractMVC] AS [vwContractMVC]) AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[NID] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[Date] >= @p__linq__1) AND ([Extent1].[Date] <= @p__linq__2)
```

in case when table is used - the query is simple:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[NID] AS [NID], 
[Extent1].[Date] AS [Date], 
[Extent1].[Column1] AS [Column1], 
[Extent1].[Column2] AS [Column2], 
[Extent1].[Column3] AS [Column3]
FROM [dbo].[Contract] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[NID] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[Date] >= @p__linq__1) AND ([Extent1].[Date] <= @p__linq__2)
```

Question is - how to get linq make simple select from view, if it's possible, of course )

I can create Stored Procedure for that, but I was hoping to use existing tables and views.

Comment: Have you looked at the query plan?  I'd be surprised if those two generate a different queryplan and perform any differently.  I'm not sure why LINQ is doing that, but in general LINQ doesn't always generate the nicest SQL.  The issue really comes up if the query plan that's generated is poor -- and in this case, I'd be willing to bet they're the same.

Comment: Eli Gassert, - yes, plans are the same - but execution time differs (not sure why, but it does differ). That's why I don't want to use the subquery created by linq - it will be slower for sure, DB is pretty big, and I should avoid such pattern.

Comment: Hamlet Hakobyan, does it matter ?

Comment: Use a stored proc and be done with it.

Comment: Robert Slaney, I'm just searching for a better solution than creating a bunch of SP's. If I don't find it - I'll certainly use procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual SQL is being created with a sub-query because you are selecting from a view. If you are not selecting from the same view multiple times just create your linq query from the actual tables, otherwise you can create a method that returns the view sql AsQueryable() and add where clauses as needed.

Code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

    namespace LinqToView
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                using (var context = new NWEntities())
                {
                    ViewQuery(context).Where(vw => vw.Product == "Foo").ToList();
                }
            }

            private static IQueryable<vwProducts_by_Categories> ViewQuery(NWEntities context)
            {
                return
                    from p in context.Products
                    join c in context.Categories on p.CategoryID equals c.CategoryID
                    select new vwProducts_by_Categories { Product = p.ProductName, Category = c.CategoryName };
            }
        }

        public class vwProducts_by_Categories
        {
            public string Product { get; set; }
            public string Category { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

which generates:

```
    SELECT 
    [Extent2].[CategoryID] AS [CategoryID], 
    [Extent1].[ProductName] AS [ProductName], 
    [Extent2].[CategoryName] AS [CategoryName]
    FROM  [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Categories] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[CategoryID] = [Extent2].[CategoryID]
    WHERE N'Foo' = [Extent1].[ProductName]
```